# How can you check if brainf*ck program is in an loop more than 5 seconds in python?

Tags: python, loops, interpreter, brainfuck

I am making a program that makes a random Brainf*ck program in python and runs it. I have an interpreter and I need it to check for long loops (more than 5 seconds).
The interpreter is:

```
while i < len(code):
    if code[i] == '<':
        if pointerLocation > 0:
            pointerLocation -= 1
    elif code[i] == '>':
        pointerLocation += 1
        if len(array) <= pointerLocation:
            array.append(0)
    elif code[i] == '+':
        array[pointerLocation] += 1
    elif code[i] == '-':
        if array[pointerLocation] > 0:
            array[pointerLocation] -= 1
    elif code[i] == '.':
        print(array[pointerLocation], chr(array[pointerLocation]))
        result += chr(array[pointerLocation])
    elif code[i] == ',':
        #x = input("Input (1 CHARACTER!):")
        x = 'h'
        #increase time if user inputs
        t1 += 5
        try:
            y = int(x)
        except ValueError:
            y = ord(x)
        array[pointerLocation] = y
    elif code[i] == '[':
        if array[pointerLocation] == 0:
            open_braces = 1
            while open_braces > 0 and i+1 < len(code):
                i += 1
                if code[i] == '[':
                    open_braces += 1
                elif code[i] == ']':
                    open_braces -= 1
    elif code[i] == ']':
        # you don't need to check array[pointerLocation] because the matching '[' will skip behind this instruction if array[pointerLocation] is zero
        open_braces = 1
        while open_braces > 0:
            if t > 5:
                return [result,code,t]
                print(123)
            i -= 1
            if code[i] == '[':
                open_braces -= 1
            elif code[i] == ']':
                open_braces += 1
        # i still gets incremented in your main while loop
        i -= 1
    i += 1
```

Sorry for the long snippet, but I do believe it is all neccessary.

Comment: What's your actual use case here? If you're trying to figure out if your program is likely to be stuck in an indefinite CPU-bound state, you don't need to detect loops at all -- you can just check whether it's been more than five seconds since the last I/O operation (`.` or `,`).

Answer (score 0):

Set up an [alarm](https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html) when you enter the loop for 5 seconds.  Cancel it when you exit.  If the signal triggers then you handle it.

A weaker version of this is to obtain the time when you enter the loop, then check on each iteration to see if it's more than 5 seconds on each iteration.

Comment: Sorry, I meant 5+ seconds loops.  Edited for clarification.

Comment: I'm not super familair with brainfuck, but is it really isomorphic to the halting problem if they just want to detect if a program takes longer than 5 seconds to run on their machine?

Comment: @CollinD No, the problem description changed after I posted the solution.

Comment: This elides the critical work of detecting when a loop is entered and exited. If you're familiar with how Brainfuck works, that's a little more interesting than it would be with languages that actually _have_ explicit loop constructs. Consequently, I would argue that (1) this answer isn't complete, and (2) the question is probably too broad to be on-topic. (Doubly so if one wants to detect not just the innermost loop but outer ones as well, or to detect loops with an arbitrary number of instructions within them).

Comment: I'd argue that doing this well is tantamount to writing a decompiler for a fairly simple assembly language; you need to decode the instructions and how they interact enough to figure out what actually _is_ a loop in the first place. Doing it poorly is a lot easier -- keep a cache of prior instruction pointer locations, and try to figure out if we're repeating ourselves -- but will often be wrong.

Comment: ...after all, what _is_ "exiting a loop" to a BF interpreter? Has one exited it as soon as one hits an instruction that hasn't been executed in prior iterations? If so, just having an `if` branch inside the loop that executes only at an iteration after the first one would be detected as "exiting the loop", so that's clearly not correct.

Comment: Does _any_ repeated instruction mean we're in a loop? Then you couldn't have functions / shared code that's called. And again, there's no looping construct, so how do we decide which instructions to check for repetition of? There are serious definitional problems that need to be solved before someone could even start to define an algorithm to use to implement the suggestions in this "answer".

Comment: I meant not in bf to check for loops but for the interpreter to stop after 5 seconds.

Comment: I changed it once.